# How to set DefaultComplexItemRenderer background alpha to 0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4, mxml

I have a simple list with a tileLayout of images. From the examples I've looked at it looks like i'm supposed to use the DefaultComplexItemRenderer. It works, and my array of images loads fine, but each item has a solid background. I need the background behind each image to have an alpha of 0. How Can I set that?

In the past i've just made a custom itemRenderer, and overrided the drawBackground function on itemRenderers, but DefaultComplexRenderer doesn't have a drawBackground function to override.

Is there another simple solution in the flex code? OR it would be awesome if someone could show me how to make a custom DefaultComplexRenderer.

NOTE:
This is a Flex MOBILE project. I know some itemRenderer's aren't friendly with mobile. Adobe says to "always do item renderers in AS3 rather than mxml" so, keep that in mind.

Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:ArrayList id="arrList">
            <s:BitmapImage source="assets/images/one.png" scaleMode="letterbox" smooth="true" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            <s:BitmapImage source="assets/images/two.png" scaleMode="letterbox" smooth="true" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            <s:BitmapImage source="assets/images/three.png" scaleMode="letterbox" smooth="true" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            <s:BitmapImage source="assets/images/four.png" scaleMode="letterbox" smooth="true" width="100%" height="100%"/>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </fx:Declarations>



<s:List id="extrasList_list" width="100%" height="100%"
                        dataProvider="{arrList}"
                        itemRenderer="spark.skins.spark.DefaultComplexItemRenderer"
                        horizontalCenter="0"
                        verticalCenter="0">
                    <s:layout>
                        <s:TileLayout requestedColumnCount="-1"
                                      requestedRowCount="-1"
                                      horizontalGap="10"
                                      verticalGap="10"
                                      orientation="rows"
                                      columnAlign="justifyUsingWidth" 
                                      />
                    </s:layout>
                </s:List>
```

Things I've tried:

this in my main css file...

```
s|DefaultComplexItemRenderer {
    contentBackgroundAlpha:0;
}
```

but i get this warning, and it doesn't work...

```
-Cannot resolve namespace qualified type 'DefaultComplexItemRenderer' in CSS selector 'DefaultComplexItemRenderer'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for trying to help guys, but I found the quickest/simple solution to be be just as simple as copying the DefaultComplexItemRender from the SDK into a custom one, and then changing this one line of code

`autoDrawBackground="false"`

It's simple and it worked.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, the above did not work. You can't set the alpha with `alternatingItemColors="[0x00000000, 0x000000]"` that doesn't work on mobile spark lists for some odd reason. But what I found got the job done.

Answer (score 0):

**[Edit]**
The `contentBackgroundAlpha` and `contentBackgroundColor` styles for a Flex `List` are somewhat misleading! You generally want to style the item renderers. In the context of a list, these styles only affect a tiny bit of "chrome" that can appear *around* the list. See below for details on styling the renderers.

If you just want to show an image, the [IconItemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/IconItemRenderer.html) is the way to go. It extends `LabelItemRenderer` so it's optimized for mobile and also has two text fields as well.

Flex List components recycle item renderers to be efficient, and only create as many renderers as needed to display what is currently visible. To do this, the list populates the renderer's `data` property. So you want to configure your item renderer using this `data` property.

An efficient way to do that is to override the setter function for `data`. Create a new Actionscript class that extends `IconItemRenderer` add this to it:

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
    super.data = value;
    // IconItemRenderer already has a BitmapImage component, it's property name is iconDisplay
    // your ArrayList should therefore only contain Strings representing the image sources
    // note how I've changed your ArrayList in the declarations tag below
    iconDisplay.source = data.imageSource;
}
```

You'll likely want to configure that `iconDisplay` BitmapImage to look how you want it. The method above may get called frequently, so you can put code that only needs to happen once somewhere else... by overriding a Flex component lifecycle method like `createChildren()`:

```
override protected function createChildren():void
{
    super.createChildren();
    iconDisplay.scaleMode="letterbox";
    iconDisplay.smooth=true;
}
```

Now tell the `List` to use your renderer w/syntax like this:

```
<s:List itemRenderer="com.yourdomain.or.whatever.MyIconItemRendererClass" />
```

**Styling the renderer:**

```
<s:List alternatingItemColors="[0xFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFF]" selectionColor="#FF0000" />
```

Another way is to override the mobile item renderer's `drawBackground()` and/or `drawBorder()` protected methods and draw your own stuff w/the graphics api (or nothing at all).

**Supplying the data:**

Instead of giving the list an array of `BitmapImage` components, you give it an array of objects that contain your data. It's better to use strongly typed objects, but this works too:

```
<fx:Declarations>
        <s:ArrayList id="arrList">
            <fx:Object imageSource="assets/images/one.png" />
            <fx:Object imageSource="assets/images/two.png" />
            <fx:Object imageSource="assets/images/three.png" />
        </s:ArrayList>
</fx:Declarations>
```

I like writing renderers in Actionscript... But there is also an MXML example in the link to `IconItemRenderer` docs at the top. It also shows how you to set the values of the two text areas in this renderer (with `labelField` and `messageField`). You can also specify a function that returns the label/message/icon values (with `labelFunction`, `messageFunction`, and `iconFunction`).

Comment: I've done some custom IconItemRenderer's in the past but i'm not sure using it would work for my situation. I'm attempting to create a like "tile" of square images on the screen. Not like a vertical rectangle list (the way the IconItemRenderer is setup by default) Is it possible if I do decide to use an IconItemRenderer, put it in a tileLayout and just display the icon? and it'll make a grid of square images?

Comment: Yesh, thanks for trying! But sorry, I'm familiar with the IconItemrenderer and I just tried your example with using a tileLayout and it still tries to stack them on top of each other like a regular list. So sorry, this does not work how I need it to.

Comment: Also, I've tried this in the past on other projects, but you should know you can't even add alpha using alternatingItemColors. Theoretically this should work, `alternatingItemColors="[0x00000000, 0x000000]"` BUT it does NOT work. The only solution for IconItemRenderers in the past and getting rid of their backgrounds, has been by overriding the drawBackground...BUT like I said up top, the complexItemRenderer doesnt let me override the drawBackground, and I cant use the IconItemRenderer because it does not lay the images out in a gride like I need them to. thanks anyway!

Comment: Actually just found a simple solution. thank you so much for trying!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you should be able to use `setStyle('contentBackgroundAlpha', 0);` on your DefaultComplexItemRenderer.

Not 100% this is what you're looking for, not really familiar with this class. Any reason you're using this over extending LabelItemRenderer?

**edit**

I believe you may want to extend [IconItemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/IconItemRenderer.html)

Check out this tutorial

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOpsDZaQrOI

Comment: If i use LabelItemRenderer, I just end up with a bunch of strings that say `[object BitmapImage]` rather than actually seeing the images. Also, I tried `s|DefaultComplexItemRenderer {
 contentBackgroundAlpha:0;
}` in my css file, but I'm getting this warning `-Cannot resolve namespace qualified type 'DefaultComplexItemRenderer' in CSS selector 'DefaultComplexItemRenderer'` I tried it anyway, but it did not work.

Comment: @brybam You need to define all the assets from your dataprovider inside your item renderer. I don't think DefaultComplexItemRenderer is the way to go. Check out this video on making a as3 mobile item renderer: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOpsDZaQrOI